# Flashed ICS i9020T image onto AT&T I9020XXKI1 baseband phone now intermittent WiFi

Tags: wi-fi, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, rom-flashing, cellular-radio

I flashed a [Nexus S i9020T Android 4.0.3 package](http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/google_crespo/VQ8PQk_V.zip) image onto my AT&T Nexus S.  The flash was a success, but the wi-fi is intermittent.  It will come on for a bit, but then lose connectivity.  In the top notification bar, the wi-fi icon goes away, but the system says that wi-fi is still on.

Could the wi-fi problem be caused by my not flashing the correct radio image after I flashed the ICS ROM?  This warning/error message is showing up in LogCat every 1 second.

> 01-31 09:49:18.824: WARN/wpa_supplicant(2202): wlan0: Failed to initiate AP scan
>
> 01-31 09:49:18.824: ERROR/wpa_supplicant(2202): ioctl[SIOCSIWPRIV] (cscan): -1

Answer (score 1):

As that's the wrong stock image for your phone there's something in it that doesn't work correctly, such as a baseband or radio image that's incorrect.

You may have luck updating the drivers: http://code.google.com/android/nexus/drivers.html#crespo

Comment: I flashed a new radio image and i can make/recieve calls and get 3g data.. wifi is flaky.  I can try that thanks